# Python Json problems

Tags: python, json

I have these lines of code

```
url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Detroit,%20Us";
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url);
data = json.load(json_obj);

print data;
```

This works on my computer at home, but when I try it on my school computer, it gives me the error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I have no clue why this happens. My computer at home runs version 2.7.6 and at school we have 2.7.3.1, idk if this helps.

Comment: Can you show code of error?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? (also, you don't need `;` at the end of lines in python)

Comment: I think @fredtantini means *behind* a proxy, which would also be my guess as to your problem :-)

Comment: Your school computer is not allowed to connect to api.openweathermap.org, it appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 11004\] getaddrinfo failed>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022945/urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed)

Comment: The link works on my school browser, and i can access the http://openweathermap.org/API too.