# How to request a url with non-unicode carachters on main domainname (not params) in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, urllib2, urlopen

I cannot request url "http://www.besondere-raumdüfte.de" with urllib2.urlopen(). 
I tried to encode string using urllib.urlencode with utf-8, idna, ascii But still doesn't work. 
Raises `URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type`.

Comment: "ü" is not a "non-unicode character". Barely *any character* qualifies as a "non-unicode character", because Unicode covers pretty much everything character-like out there. It's a "non-ASCII character".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `u"http://www.besondere-raumdüfte.de/".encode('idna')`. Please note how the source string is a Unicode constant (the `u` prefix).

The result is an URL usable with `urlopen()`.

If you have a domain name with non-ASCII characters *and* the rest of the URL contains non-ASCII characters, you need to `.encode('idna')` the domain part and `iri2uri()` the rest.

Comment: Thanks that works, I remember I tried to encode with 'idna' and urllib2.urlopen the string **without u at the beginning** but does 'u' before string matter smth.

Comment: @AbdyresulCharyev: oh yes, using a byte string instead of a Unicode sting is one of the most frequent mistakes, I did it myself many times %)

Answer (score 0):

You are working with an [iri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) and not a [uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI), what you have to do is convert it correctly. The following is an example on how to do it:

```
from httplib2 import iri2uri

def iri_to_uri(iri):
    """Transform a unicode iri into a ascii uri."""
    if not isinstance(iri, unicode):
        raise TypeError('iri %r should be unicode.' % iri)
    return bytes(iri2uri(iri))
```

Once you have an uri you should be able to use urllib2.

Comment: To check I tried 
`urllib2.urlopen(bytes(iri2uri("http://www.besondere-raumdüfte.de")))` But gives the error:
 URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Comment: You are probably behind a firewall, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847649/opening-websites-using-urllib2-from-behind-corporate-firewall-11004-getaddrinf

Comment: Funny, but it is because I forgot to put u before string quot :) after I put it it worked. I guess u defines the string as unicode string.   Thanks.