# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am actually writing a code to check whether the links are direct or error or redirect or file download link

when i write these lines

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
```

I get error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1173, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1148, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Y is this error occuring any ideas?? Is this because my company doenst allow to access websites this way?Thanks

Comment: related: [opening websites using urllib2 from behind corporate firewall - 11004 getaddrinfo failed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4847649/4279)

Comment: It could be a DNS lookup issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16904232/648689

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thats right!!

Comment: @JimB I had to set proxy which I have solved rt now...Thanks!!

Comment: stuck in the same error, need help

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but did you check http://google.com in your browser? What response do you get?

As of now, HTTP connections are forwarded to the HTTPS and this works for me:
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com')
print response.read()

```
    <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's informati
on, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for
." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta
 content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){
window.google={kEI:'WjgxV8I8jLCPA5iGn4gK',kEXPI:'1350654,3700257,3700388,4029815,4031109,4032677,4036509,4036527,4038012,4039268,4
042553,4042792,4043492,4045841,4048347,4049557,4051558,4052304,4056038,4057170,4057739,4057836,4058299,4058337,4059767,4061155,406
1181,4061552,4062222,4062287,4062299,4062333,4062407,4062632,4062706,4062971,4062987,4063095,4063111,4063126,4063829,4063879,40639
29,4064307,4064318,4064449,4064496,4064501,4064815,4064931,4065592,4065787,4065796,4065855,4065945,4066098,4066101,4066615,4066662
,4066706,4067087,4067307,8300096,8300273,8503585,8504026,8504107,8504280,8504282,8504308,8504456,8504522,10200083,10201847',authus
er:0,kscs:'c9c918f0_24'};google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAt
tribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttr
ibute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};go
ogle.ml=function(){return null};google.wl=function(a,b){try{google.ml(Error(a),!1,b)}catch(c){}};google.time=function(){return(new
 Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,c,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,c,e,g);if(""!=a){b=new Image;var d=google.lc,f=google.li;d[f]
```