# Tweepy:Failed to send request: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: tweepy

I am simply trying to get the username and I end up with 
above  error.
My internet connection uses proxy and I have already modified my code
to use urllib2 but nothing seems to be working here in below code.

```
import tweepy 
import dbapi 
import urllib, urllib2, httplib

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":'proxyurl'})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support,urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener) 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)  
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)  

api = tweepy.API(auth)  
print(api.me().screen_name)
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: have you tried to look through tweepy sources to find the location and exact reason of a mistake?

Comment: oh... I found nothing. Do you have such a mistake without proxy_support? Just tweepy?

Comment: I tried with options with or without this proxy_support but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: and how about urlopen() any website? the same mistake?

Comment: import urllib, urllib2, httplib

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":'http://proxy:8083/'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support,urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener) 
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.co.in')   ***** this doesnt throw any error but it couldnt open google website also.

Comment: hm... what about your 'proxy:8083/'? could it be a DNS error?

Comment: I just  found one forum where it says that If your internet connection fails, then we  would get below error:
"TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed"
however in my case net connection is working fine. Not sure now what could be the cause?

Comment: [Wiki-getaddrinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo) I think it is really dns problem. your lookup for 'proxy' is failing. Have you tried ip:port instead of domain-name:port?

Comment: unfortunately, replacing proxy server with IP adress also didnt fix:(

Comment: that's very strange... have you tried sudo? :)

Comment: Sudo  is for  linux right?

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709583/urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed   also

Comment: dns lookup fail... as I said... but it still doesn't work

Comment: totally agree with you.. May be I will try once when i am out of office network without proxy.