# urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm following a video tutorial.

So here's the code snippet

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen('http://sixty-north/c/t.txt') as story:
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
        for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
```

I'm able to access `http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt` in my browser.

However when I type this into command prompt: `python words.py` I get this error:

```
C:\New folder>python words.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1248, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 906, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 822, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 417, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "words.py", line 2, in <module>
    with urlopen('http://sixty-north/c/t.txt') as story:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 487, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1274, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1251, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: If you try to ping the host-name `sixty-north` do you expect to get a reply?

Comment: you can refer this link also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847649/opening-websites-using-urllib2-from-behind-corporate-firewall-11004-getaddrinf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such host: `sixty-north`. Replace `sixty-north` with `sixty-north.com` (notice: `.com` at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Change host: `sixty-north` with `sixty-north.com`
And also, Restart your Internet Connection.
Your Internet is not working properly.