# Splinter does not visit the URL inspite of correct proxy settings

Tags: proxy, python-3.4, spyder, splinter

I have added proxy settings to the browser using below code:

```
proxyIP = 'some IP'
proxyPort = some_port

proxy_settings = {'network.proxy.type': 1,
       'network.proxy.http': proxyIP,
       'network.proxy.http_port': proxyPort,
       'network.proxy.ssl': proxyIP,
       'network.proxy.ssl_port':proxyPort,
       'network.proxy.socks': proxyIP,
       'network.proxy.socks_port':proxyPort,
       'network.proxy.ftp': proxyIP,
       'network.proxy.ftp_port':proxyPort           
      }

with Browser('firefox',profile_preferences=proxy_settings) as browser:
```

Firefox browser opens up & when I check the proxy settings, they are loaded with correct values. But it fails to load the url with `browser.visit('https://www.google.com/')`
It throws the error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I even added `'accept_untrusted_certs': True` in proxy_settings incase that would help. But to no avail.

If I manually enter a url in the browser-instance that gets created, it successfully visits the page.

- Is something missing?
- Is there a way to start the browser with its default profile (so that all proxy
  settings, extensions, etc. get loaded automatically)? I tried `Browser(profile='profile_path')`, it did not work out.

In hope...

P.S: The same code (without proxy settings) works perfectly well on a system with direct internet.

Comment: well, you set the http proxy, but you're visiting a page with https. I think you need to set the https proxy too.

Comment: @Roberto: I thought SSL with HTTP settings take care of HTTPS, no? Plus, these are the only options provided by firefox (or the ones that I am aware of). Is there a different setting that you are aware of, to explicitly set a HTTPS proxy?

Comment: There should exist two separate settings... Specifically for Firefox, "This preference specifies the proxy server to use for the given protocol. Possible protocols: HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, Gopher, SOCKS"
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.%28protocol%29#Firefox

Comment: Did you try it, anyways? It's easier to try than to think about it :p  
`network.proxy.https': proxyIP,`  
`network.proxy.https_port': proxyPort,`

Comment: Hey @Roberto, thanks for the response & persuasion. HTTPS from the list of protocols is handled by HTTP & SSL setting. Nevertheless, I tried `network.proxy.https` & `network.proxy.https_port` settings to no vail :-(

Comment: Hmm apparently this might be a known problem with Splinter. I wish I could test it here instead of just sending you to a webpage, but see if any of the workaround solutions in [this thread](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/issues/120) help. The issue is also described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/splinter-users/G1oxcsqfcrA/I07j0YkOnB0J). There is a StackOverflow thread about urllib2 on Py2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481398/python-urllib2-https-and-proxy-ntlm-authentication); possibly the problem persists for urllib on Py3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **selenium**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "<you_proxy_ip>:<your_proxy_port>"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: That might work, but does not really answer the question.

Comment: Yes it's an alternative because the bug is known by Splinter and not resolved yet.