# Requests Proxy NTLM Authentication (Without Hardcoding Username and Password)

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, proxy, ntlm

I'm trying to send requests to an HTTPS website behind corporate proxy that requires authentication.

The below code works:

```
import requests
import urllib

requests.get('https://google.com',
             proxies={
                 'http': 'http://myusername:mypassword@10.20.30.40:8080',
                 'https': 'http://myusername:mypassword@10.20.30.40:8080'
             },
             verify=False)
```

but I want to avoid hardcoding the username and password in the script file, especially that we have to reset our passwords every 60 days. I need it to automatically authenticate as the logged-in Windows user, same behavior as a browser.

I looked online and learned that this is not possible through `requests` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481398/python-urllib2-https-and-proxy-ntlm-authentication), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276955/ntlm-proxy-without-password), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531038/python-request-with-authenticated-proxy-without-exposing-username-and-password), [4](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/issues/104)) and I would have to resort to something like `pycurl` or [`px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px) but all examples online had username and password provided explicitly. There was also [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/755936) utilizing `win32com.client` but I have no idea how to use this in place of `requests`.